# Sum over permutations is 1

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations, combinatorial-identities

This might be easy, but let's see.

> **Question 1.** If $\mathfrak{S}_n$ is the group of permutations on $[n]$, then is the following true?
>   $$\sum_{\pi\in\mathfrak{S}_n}\prod_{j=1}^n\frac{j}{\pi(1)+\pi(2)+\cdots+\pi(j)}=1.$$

**Update.** After Lucia's answer, I got motivated to ask:

> **Question 2.** Let $z_1,\dots,z_n$ be indeterminates. Is this identity true too?
>   $$\sum_{\pi\in\mathfrak{S}_n}\prod_{j=1}^n\frac{z_j}{z_{\pi(1)}+z_{\pi(2)}+\cdots+z_{\pi(j)}}=1.$$

**Update.** Now that we've an analytic and an algebraic proof, is there a combinatorial argument too? At least for **Question 1**.

Comment: Is it true for $n=2$? 3? 4?

Comment: Yes, for $n<7$.

Comment: Are all these identities in question computer-generated?

Comment: Computer-tested. In the present case, you can't go far with your data because $\mathfrak{S}_n$ grows very quickly. So, you also need a "leap of faith".

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes.  Write the sum as 
$$ 
\sum_{\pi \in S_n} n! \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\pi(1) x_1} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(\pi(1)+\pi(2)) x_2} \ldots \int_0^{\infty} e^{-(\pi(1) + \ldots +\pi(n))x_n} dx_n \ldots dx_1. 
$$ 
Upon writing $y_n = x_n$, $y_{n-1}=x_n+x_{n-1}$, etc this becomes 
$$ 
\sum_{\pi \in {S_n} } n! \int_{y_1 \ge y_2 \ge \ldots y_n \ge 0} e^{-\sum_{i=1}^{n} \pi(i)y_i } dy_1 \ldots dy_n. 
$$ 
Since the sum is over all $\pi \in S_n$, it doesn't matter that we are in the region $y_1 \ge y_2 \ge \ldots \ge y_n$ -- for any other ordering of the non-negative variables $y_i$, the answer would be the same.  So recast the above as 
$$ 
\int_0^{\infty} \ldots \int_0^{\infty} \sum_{\pi \in S_n} e^{-\sum_{i=1}^{n} \pi(i) y_i} dy_1 \ldots dy_n 
= \sum_{\pi \in S_n} \frac{1}{n!} = 1.
$$

Comment: Interesting approach. Please see my update.

Comment: Same proof works.

Answer (score 29):

Here is a probabilistic, or, if you wish, combinatorial proof. Assume that we have $n$ baskets containing $z_1,\dots,z_n$ balls respectively (well, let them be positive integers). Choose a random ball (all balls have equal probability) and forbid all the balls from its basket. Repeat with $n-1$ remaining baskets and so on. What is the probability that we consecutively get balls from baskets $\pi_n,\pi_{n-1},\dots,\pi_1$? Yes, it equals $$\prod_{j=1}^n\frac{z_{\pi_j}}{z_{\pi(1)}+z_{\pi(2)}+\cdots+z_{\pi(j)}}$$
(we start multiplying from $j=n$ downto $j=1$). The sum of all these probabilities equals 1.

Comment: I like it, neat.

Answer (score 22):

Purely algebraic proof. We induct on $n$. Fix $\pi_n$. This part of the sum equals $z_{\pi_n}/(z_1+\dots+z_n)$ by induction proposition. Now sum up by all values of $\pi_n$.

Comment: And the identity holds for $n=0$ :)

Comment: @js21 Indeed, this is important!