# Sum over permutations involving sign

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations, combinatorial-identities

The problem is to evaluate the following sum over all permutations $\sigma\in S_{d}$ of $\{1,2,...,d\}$:

> $\displaystyle\sum_{\sigma\in S_{d}}\text{sgn}(\sigma)\displaystyle\frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^{d}(\sigma_{1} + \sigma_{2} + ... + \sigma_{i})}$.

This is similar to [Question 1 here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/262349/sum-over-permutations-is-1) except the sign term. The conjecture is that our sum equals $\prod_{k=1}^{d-1}\frac{(k!)^{2}}{(2k+1)!}$. The problem and the conjecture arises from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3380330).

Comment: Hm, can this perhaps be phrased as a determinant? Smells like some type of Vandermonde-determinant?

Comment: @PerAlexandersson: That is where it came from: see the [original question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3367836/241132). It is the leading coefficient of sum of a Vandermonde polynominal.

Comment: Here is one thought looking at the conjectured form: $\frac{(k!)^{2}}{(2k+1)!} = \frac{(\Gamma(k+1))^{2}}{\Gamma(2k+2)} = B(k+1,k+1)$. This suggests that the sum may be expressible as product of integrals: $\prod_{k=1}^{d-1}\left(\int_{0}^{1} t_{k}^{k}(1-t_{k})^{k}\:{\rm{d}}t_{k}\right)$.